# Is it appropriate to edit someone else's answer for politeness?

Tags: discussion, new-users, editing-help, abuse

When reviewing posts by new users, I saw an answer that contained helpful information but also said that the original question contained nonsense that obviously wouldn't work. I left a comment suggesting that the response be toned down, since, if it had been obvious to the poster, they wouldn't have asked the question and that fear of derision deters my college students from posting to Stack Overflow.

Did I do the right thing? I didn't flag the message, since it wasn't clear to me that it had crossed the line to rude or abusive. Should I have flagged it or edited myself, was commenting the right thing, or should I have done something else (including nothing)?

I'm not including a link to the answer since I don't want to pick on the answerer. I'm sure this issue comes up a lot.

Comment: Yes, you did the right thing. You can also link the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) if you like. Everyone is welcome to edit such stuff out of posts (and fix other issues, like spelling etc.) and since you have more than 2000 points of reputation your edit wouldn't need to be reviewed. Also you can flag such a post, I would only do that if there is very bad language. Saying some post contained nonsense is not nice, but doesn't warrant a flag, in my point of view.

Comment: If there is "meta" noise in any post edit it out. Period. If an edit of the question is needed to rectify the "non-sense", edit the question as well. Flag for a moderator if the edit is rolled-back or if you encounter any other backslash.

Comment: Good edits are also those that remove non-meaty substance of the post.

Comment: The site founder [has blogged](https://blog.codinghorror.com/) about the wisdom of letting students use SO.  Start reading at "This is why I cringe so hard I practically turn myself inside out when people on Twitter mention that they have pointed their students at Stack Overflow. What you'd want for a beginner or a student in the field of programming is almost the exact opposite of what Stack Overflow does at every turn:"

Comment: @HansPassant In the capstone course, I teach my students when and how to post to Stack Overflow. The post you linked to was about beginners; not all students are beginners (and not all beginners are students).

Comment: @Braiam I read the response to the question you linked to (thank you) but do not think it directly addresses the question I raised. It mentions removing irrelevancies but not specifically editing for tone.